# How to extract the geographic coordinates of specific pixel locations?

Tags: numpy, geospatial, raster, gdal

This question has no attempted code because I don't know where to begin.

I have a raster image with spatial information.

I did some processing to it in OpenCV, for which the output was a **second** Numpy Array that is a series of pixel locations that form vertices for lines to pass through (see image). The problem is, these vertices are in pixel index positions, not geographic coordinates. I would like to bring the coords from this second array into GIS, but I can't without spatial reference.

I need to assign geographic coordinates to each of these pixel index positions. How can I do this? The array with the line coords in pixel space is in the attached image. How can I get those in to literal lat/lon, meters, etc., using the original GeoTIFF?

[image]

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443906/pixel-array-position-to-lat-long-gdal-python) answer your question?

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: the linked post shows two methods for how to get coordinates for an array index given the geo-info of a Raster (GeoTiff). How's that different from what you want?

Comment: You're right, sorry. Looked too quickly at first. Thank you.

Comment: (removed automatic comment)