# IndexError: index 525 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 462

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasterio

I am following this guy's code from here: [pixel/array position to lat long gdal Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443906/pixel-array-position-to-lat-long-gdal-python) and more specifically this:

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('rasters/raster.tif') as map_layer:
    pixels2coords = map_layer.xy(pixel_x, pixel_y)  #input px, py
```

in order to translate pixel coordinates into lat, long.

My .tif image has this shape:

map_layer.width =  715

map_layer.height =  462

When I give a random `pixel_x < 462` everything is fine (for any `pixel_y`).

However, when I give a random `pixel_x > 462`

For instance, I get this error:

```
IndexError: index 525 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 462
```

I checked the image as you can see above and it loads it correctly. I mean the width and height are correct. I have spent all day trying to fix it, I do not why this happens...Any idea?

I cannot post the whole code is...it is many lines and too complicated to post a minimum runnable code.